# Xdebug not working with NetBeans 12.2, Windows 10

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to set up Xdebug (version 3.1.1) with NetBeans 12.2 on Windows 10.

I've followed the directions on the xdebug website utilizing the wizard to analyze the `phpinfo()` and the wizard says I'm running the latest xdebug build, but NetBeans still doesn't start it correctly. Clicking on debug in Netbeans launches my website, but it does not load and the debug options are greyed out, besides ending the debug session. Launching the website normally works. I've got the port set to 9003, the `mode` is set to "debug", `start_with_request` is set as "yes" and the `remote_handler` is "dbgp".  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I'm running Java Version 8, Update 311. Also updated my problem to reflect updates to the upgrade notice from version 2 to 3.

EDIT 2: Shortened and clarified question. I also checked to see if my virus protection/firewall was the cause and it doesn't seem like that's causing it either. Link to `xdebug_info()` via drive:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJCs8n30CCP4zI9KDAopaIV-lRT3k9BM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's unlikely but possible that your version of Java might be relevant. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Just double checked and I'm running Version 8, update 311. Also updated original question with the version 2 to 3 revisions.

Comment: [1] OK, not an issue in that case. [2] Please also update your question to link to those _"directions on the website"_ that you are following, so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I suggest you 1) show your live Xdebug config (`xdebug_info()` output captured in the same way you are trying to debug: via web page or CLI); 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it says https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug 3's default port is `9003`, and not `9000`, as per the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide). `remote_host` is also no longer an existing setting name, again, as per the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

Comment: Oh I see, it's been a long time since I've dealt with Netbeans and had to do a fresh install. The documentation is a little all over the place between the xdebug site, Netbeans error messages and other postings. It looks like at this point the main three configurations that are needed, besides the zend_extension is defining the mode, remote_handler still, and start_with_request. If that's all, I'm now getting it to try the connection, though it times out now.

Comment: `remote_handler` has been removed, as there was only one possible value.